# Redis: Sum of SCORES in Sorted Set

Tags: sum, redis, sortedset

What's the best way to get the sum of SCORES in a Redis sorted set?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only option I think is iterating the sorted set and computing the sum client side.

Comment: thanks! Yeah, I guess this is probably too specific of a feature for Redis to bother implementing... esp. since I may not even be doing something advisable. I'm using a zset to store a user's received gift ids & the sending user ids and the SCORE is the # of times that same gift has been received from the same sender. E.g., `ZINCR 123:gifts 1 "3|345"` sends the gift w id 3 from user 345 to user 123. So, I want to get the total gifts a user has received. See? Perhaps there is better way to implement this? It is like Facebook Gift API. Redis rules! :) Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 15):

Available since Redis v2.6 is the most awesome ability to execute Lua scripts on the Redis server. This renders the challenge of summing up a Sorted Set's scores to trivial:

```
local sum=0
local z=redis.call('ZRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1, 'WITHSCORES')

for i=2, #z, 2 do 
    sum=sum+z[i]
end

return sum
```

Runtime example:

```
~$ redis-cli zadd z 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e
(integer) 5
~$ redis-cli eval "local sum=0 local z=redis.call('ZRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1, 'WITHSCORES') for i=2, #z, 2 do sum=sum+z[i] end return sum" 1 z
(integer) 15
```

Comment: An important note is that Redis server-side lua scripts blocks EVERYTHING, which can be a dealbreaker in most cases. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30896608/2440

Answer (score 6):

If the sets are small, and you don't need killer performance, I would just iterate (zrange/zrangebyscore) and sum the values client side.

If, on the other hand, you are talking about many thousands - millions of items, you can always keep a reference set with running totals for each user and increment/decrement them as the gifts are sent.

So when you do your `ZINCR 123:gifts 1 "3|345"`, you could do a seperate ZINCR command, which could be something like this:

```
ZINCR received-gifts 1 <user_id>
```

Then, to get the # of gifts received for a given user, you just need to run a ZSCORE:

```
ZSCORE received-gifts <user_id>
```

Comment: Incremental counting wins by far for online problems. Scan should only be used in offline algorithms, IMHO, as nobody can predict future dataset growth. This answer should be the one accepted.

Oh, and btw: one might write a custom command that does both (adding to a set and incrementing the counter; updating a value and adjusting the counter, deleting from set & ...)

Comment: Obviously this answer is quite old, but, why use a ZSET at all for the "separate command"?  It's not clear to me from your answer, as far as I can tell it would work just as well (and use less memory) to just use INCR/GET.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little lua script that maintains the zset score total as you go, in a counter with key postfixed with '.ss'. You can use it instead of ZADD.

```
local delta = 0
for i=1,#ARGV,2 do
    local oldScore = redis.call('zscore', KEYS[1], ARGV[i+1])
    if oldScore == false then
        oldScore = 0
    end
    delta = delta - oldScore + ARGV[i]
end
local val = redis.call('zadd', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))
redis.call('INCRBY', KEYS[1]..'.ss', delta)
```

Comment: That script should not construct the key within lua (`KEYS[1]..'.ss'`), which "violates the EVAL command semantics as all the keys that the script uses should be passed using the KEYS array" --
 https://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: @Jonathan you are right, the key for the total score should also be passed in the KEYS[]